# How to save the edited .csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have sensor readings stored in csv files and now I am adding some more values to these files. How can I save these files in new locations in csv format for future use.

Comment: I like using `csv.DictWriter`

Comment: You can use **pandas** function : **to_csv()**

Comment: The question was edited to clean up the grammar. If the meaning has been changed, please feel free to [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39833520/edit) yourself to return it to its original meaning.

Comment: Importing pandas just to use to_csv would be overkill if you're not already using it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this guide: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/

Basically the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html) does what you need:

```
import csv
```